# How can i record video on my website？

Tags: flash, video, web, rtmp, recorder

I have tried to use red5 demo, but there have some bugs(the record-file's time always less than the really recorded). i have no idea how to fix it.
My user just record video(by flash or other) on my website, the video recorder need upload the video to server(upload by flash or other).
i just wanna find a simple way or simple demo code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RED5 0.8 version`.

That will solve the issue with truncation of recording.